# Stop for loop python with step0 and step1 with consequence sub-step

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops

How to stop this for-loop, I want to do step0 1 time and then start the while loop 5 times then stop.

```
for x in range (5):
    print("step0")
    while x >= 0:
        print("step1")
        for x in range (5):
            print("sub-step",x)
```

**Result (infinite loop)**

```
step0
step1
sub-step 0
sub-step 1
sub-step 2
sub-step 3
sub-step 4
step1
sub-step 0   
sub-step 1
sub-step 2
sub-step 3
sub-step 4
step1
sub-step 0
sub-step 1
sub-step 2
sub-step 3
sub-step 4
.....................
```

**Expected Result**

```
step0 (1 times)  
step1 (5 times)
   sub-steps(following step1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("step0")
for x in range (5):
   print("step1")
   for i in range (5):
     print("sub-step",i)
```

Next time try to think about each step you want to, step0 is only call once, so why put it into a for-loop?

Step1 is called 5 times, you got it, a for loop, then substep is called 5 times each times step1 is called, so each time you call step1, for-loop substep 5 times, gl !

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do step0 1 time

Don't add the for loop then. What's the intention to keep for loop for step0?

> then start the while loop 5 times then stop.

Add counter variable or a simple for loop for the part you want to execute 5 times.